# Hall Effect Current Sensor IC Data Sheet

Tags: current-measurement, datasheet

I'm feeling like an idiot here.  I've found this great little IC that will do the job I want but I can't seem to figure out what the max voltage is that can be supplied for sensing.

The IC runs on 5Vdc and the version I want to use is the 30A size.

I'm trying to sense when a 100W RF amplifier is working.  The amplifier runs on 13.8Vdc and has a standby current of about 0.5A but when it's working it jumps to 21-23A.

Being fairly new to the whole thing I was hoping someone could point out where on the data sheet it says I'm good-to-go or DON'T DO IT MAN you're going to be making magic blue smoke.

Looking at the datasheet makes me think there is no friggin way a tiny IC can handle this much juice running through it without it melting.  Am I missing something?  It looks like they say it needs to be wired in series with the amplifier.
[ACS714-DataSheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS714-Datasheet.ashx)

Comment: I've worked with the Allegro ACS71[2-4] ICs. Yes, all the current does go through the IC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have it correct, the device should be wired in series with the amplifier. 
The pins 1,2 and 3,4 are isolated from the hall sensor circuitry. They are simply a conduction path with a nominal resistance of 1.2mΩ, so even at 30A the maximum dissipation is only 30^2 * 0.0012 = 1.08W

Hall sensing is an isolated technique, this IC just has the current p[ath fixed rather than needing to position it over a current carrying trace as with other hall ICs

[This page](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs.aspx) on Allegros site explains:

[image: Hall IC]

Answer (score 1):

66 mV/amp x 30 amp < 2 Volts on the output.  Sound to me like you're good to go.

1.2mOhm resistance on the input gives \$ P = I^2 R \$ = a very small number for 30 amps and 1.2mOhm